# Spring Repository ignore case on nested entity's field

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I have

```
public class User {
  ...
  private UserCredentials credentials;
  ...
}
```

```
public class UserCredentials {
  ...
  private String username;
  ...
}
```

I want to add a find-one-by method in my `User` repository, that finds a `User` by its credential's username, ignoring case. So, I tried `User findByCredentials_UsernameIgnoreCaseEquals(final String username)`, but get an exception caused by

> org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property lowercase found for type String! Traversed path: UserCredentials.username.

I tried a few other method names, but get the same exception. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Check carefully your naming convention: `username` or `userName`, check the `getter setter` as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone who answered. I should have posted the full exception in my question because after reviewing it again, I realized the error was with a method declared in a different repository.

Comment: For other people with the same problem it would be helpful to include more information (such as the exception which you mention), as they may have the same issue

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see this until now. The logs are long-gone, but I will be sure to do this moving forward.

Answer (score 1):

Try as below no need  `_`. And ensure you have relationship within user and user credentials table like `oneToone or onetomany` and entity have all required annotations.

```
findByCredentialsUsernameIgnoreCaseEquals(final String username);
```

Comment: Same exception. I do have the following annotations: `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false, orphanRemoval = true)`.

Comment: what exception you have

Answer (score 1):

this is jpa reference in spring boot

> https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation

**you don't need this Symbol with jpa query (_) just Upper case when end Your KeyWords**

Comment: Posting an answer with the same content that someone else has already posted is not considered good. Also `_` is still a working option to separate fields if the OP wants to use it.

Comment: i am posted reference link with note not same the answer thanks 2